# decimal input filter android

Tags: android, regex

I want to make an EditText to take decimal values where 2 digits after decimal point would be allowed(optional). Values can be:

xxxx

xxxx.x

xx.xx

.xx

.x

x.x

I've tried so many solutions found in S/O and I've found proper regex to meet my solution. But none is fulfilling my requirements. some solution meets requirement but doesn't allow to edit before decimal point. Suppose, when edittext value is .xx then can't edit before decimal point(.).

can anyone point out the proper solution.

N.B.: using maxLength property in EditText.

Comment: What is the regex supposed to do? Match all the decimals?

Comment: what are you needs as o/p?

Comment: Could you find a solution? I've same problem. I can't add new char before decimal point...

Comment: @atasoyh, couldn't find any regex solution, worked with TextWatcher to overcome the situation.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);       
            if(!matcher.matches())
                return "";
            return null;
        }


    }
```

and set filter to Edit Text

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(10, 2) });
```

Comment: I've used this also. This meets my requirement, but doesn't allow modification before decimal point(.)

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: Use your solution, put .33 value in Edittext and please try to add something before decimal point(.). I'm sure it wouldn't happen.